# I have to convert varchar data into datetime in Sybase as below

Tags: sybase, type-conversion

I have data columns timestamp, message, etc., in a table.

Example :

```
column 1 - timestamp has '3/7/2013 9:30:40 AM'
column 2 - message has '6Q201303077981 ,MAR 07 2013 09:30:00,167,P,NYSE,CD,0000.0500,PARTIAL EXECUTION             
,20130312,000006.35,000000.11,000005.25,0000127.0000,0000623.0000, ,0037.160000,0000000.0000,0000.000000,0037.160000,PEXE'
```

Now I need output as

```
column1 - timestamp as '3/7/2013 9:30:40 AM'
column2 - message as '3/7/2013 9:30:00 AM'
column3 - diff as 40
```

Please help on this query...

Comment: I already tried till (SELECT timestamp, substring(_message, 17, 20) AS _message FROM QueInDBQ WHERE timestamp > '3/7/2013 12:00:00 AM')the and I am getting output as timestamp _message 3/7/2013 9:30:40 AM MAR 07 2013 09:30:00, help me to get further output...

Comment: i dont really get how your table is looking like and how your output needs to be looking. can you please get bit more detailed?

Comment: Dom, table have multiple columns, in that column - timestamp is a DATETIME datatype,column - _message is VARCHAR datatype, now I need output as below, this is an example where I took one record to show you.     column1 - timestamp as '3/7/2013 9:30:40 AM' column2 - message as '3/7/2013 9:30:00 AM' column3 - diff as 40

Comment: Is this [tag:sybase-asa], [tag:sybase-ase], [tag:sybase-iq], or [tag:sqlanywhere]? Trying to clean up the [tag:sybase] tag...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to use a convert function to convert the varchar in a datetime datatype. Once you have this you can use a date function to see the difference.

For more details about convert please see the sybase manual here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks125.htm

For more details about the date diff function please see the sybase manual here:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks137.htm

once you have found the correct functions you can do something like this:

```
  select timestamp, convert(xxxxx), datediff(xxxx) from table
```